# Bank ER Notation Example

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a basic ER diagram for a bank and was just after some input on how it could be improved.

I created it in paint as a quick sketch as I don't have the necessary software at the moment.

[image]

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.